# ActiveMQ Artemis latency issue

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a cluster with 6 nodes of ActiveMQ Artemis (version 2.27.1) - i work with 3 servers, which on each one there is master and slave node.

As part of my test, i send something like 10,000 messages per minute into specific queue and watch the consuming latency results using my OpenSearch dashboard.

When i start my nodes by pairs - master and his corresponding slave on each iteration, it works normally, and i dont see any latency.

But When i start the nodes by the official recommended order of Artemis documentation, or in any other way, i am having latency.

here are some results of my test, and the difference between the scenarios:
[artemis-latency-test-results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giEtz.png)

Comment: Can you provide a way to reproduce exactly what you're seeing? Perhaps you could also reduce the complexity of the configuration to only exactly what is necessary to reproduce the problem. That would make it simpler for others to see what you're seeing.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant reproduce a test for example because it is application oriented...

Comment: After an investigation of both situations, i saw that the messaging distribution was affected. in the scenarios that i have latency i can see an equal distribution between all the nodes. But, in the no-latency scenario i see that only one node receives messages, and the other nodes are not. So it might be reasonable that the load balancing and data sharing affected the performance and caused some latency.

Comment: I added a [new section](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/main/docs/user-manual/en/clusters.md#performance-considerations) to the documentation to help clarify this kind of situation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! it does make things clear, and i will work by the most suitable option in this tradeoff equation.